# SQL Server does not refresh functions

Tags: sql-server, database, function, schema

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have two functions under `Programmatibility > Functions > Table-valued Functions`.

The first one retrieves a collection of all available columns and records.
The second one filters out the first one with an Id check.

Let's say I have a `Customers` table.

The first function looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetCustomers]() 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN 
        SELECT 
            C.CustomerId AS Id, 
            C.CustomerName AS Name 
        FROM 
            Customers AS C
```

and I call it like so `SELECT * FROM fnGetCustomers()`.

The second one looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetCustomerById]
    (@CustomerId AS INT) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN 
        SELECT * 
        FROM fnGetCustomers() 
        WHERE (Id = @CustomerId)
```

and I call it like so `SELECT * FROM fnGetCustomerById(1)`.

My problem is when I add a new column to my `Customers` table scheme.

First I edit `fnGetCustomers` to include the new column like so.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetCustomers]() 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN 
        SELECT 
            C.CustomerId AS Id, 
            C.CustomerName AS Name, 
            C.CustomerPhone AS Phone 
        FROM 
            Customers AS C
```

The `fnGetCustomers` works fine after the modification. Though all of the other functions, like `fnGetCustomerById`, that depend on this specific one miss the new column. Despite using `*` in the selection query.

I can solve the problem by `Right-Click on function > Modify > Execute!` on each one of the functions.

I guess something runs internally and refreshes them.

My database uses a great number of functions that depend on this specific basic one, so it's almost impossible to locate and "modify > execute" all of them.
What can be done so the database scheme updates/refresh itself automatically?

Comment: You call it like so? Or you have a view that calls it like so?

Comment: No Views are used. I just run a query in my .NET application or on a new sql file with `SELECT * FROM fnGetCustomerById(1)`. Either way the new column is missing. I tried Righ click > Refresh on my database, but still. I have to "execute" each of my function so it is refreshed.

Comment: When you use `*` instead an object it doesn't mean it'll evaluate the columns in the objects queried everytime. The columns for `*` will be evaluated at the time you `CREATE`/`ALTER` the object and that's it. If you add, remove a column it won't update the definition of the `VIEW`/`FUNCTION` etc. This is why you should always declare you columns in your objects and not use `*`. If you then  update the definition of the underlying object, and need to expose that data in other objects, you need to update those other objects too.

Comment: You need to run `EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule @name = N'[dbo].[fnGetCustomerById]';`. But really you shouldn't be using `*` in that function. If you add a column to the source, add it to the caller, too. I prevent this metadata caching problem by making my functions with schemabinding - this prevents * and makes sure you can't change an object without knowing about the dependencies it will affect.

Comment: Even if I declare each column separately, that means I have to edit each of my functions separately as well. Is there any way that sql performs a refresh on all of its objects?

Comment: *"that means I have to edit each of my functions separately as well"* Yes, it does, and that is exactly what you should be doing. This is when things like source control and database projects become invaluable.

Comment: I didn't know that using `*` checks the columns only on `CREATE/ALTER` statements.  It seems like I have to get my hands dirty then.  I will go with declaring each column on each of my function, cause I may have more trouble when I have to deploy the new schema to the customers automatically. Thank you all!

Comment: New columns output by views or objects shouldn't be a surprise. `SELECT *` is bad for so many reasons...